# Run command in `before_migrate.rb` as user with sudo privileges with AWS OpsWorks

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, gulp, chef-infra, aws-opsworks

In my Rails app, I'm trying to run a gulp task during deployment, which adds a css file to a directory inside the `public` directory. In the deployment log, I see that the task runs successfully, but when I SSH into the server, I don't see the file.

```bash
[2016-09-24T01:35:02+00:00] INFO: Processing execute[create critical css] action run   (/srv/www/toaster/releases/20160924013146/deploy/before_migrate.rb line 43)
[2016-09-24T01:35:03+00:00] INFO: execute[create critical css] ran successfully
```

While I'm connected to the server via SSH and change my user to the deploy user with `sudo su deploy` and then run the gulp task, the file gets create.

What am I doing wrong?

The line in `before_migrate` looks like this...

```bash
execute 'create critical css' do
  user 'deploy'
  cwd release_path
  command 'gulp criticalCss'
end
```

The task in my gulpfile looks like this...

```js
gulp.task('criticalCss', function() {
  glob('./public/assets/theme_templates/v3/application-*.css', function(err, matches) {
    var full_css = matches[0]

    penthouse({
      url : 'http://performance-site.s2.fanbread.com/blogs/performance-benchmark',
      css : full_css,
      width: 375,
      height: 667
    }, function(err, criticalCss) {
      console.log(err)
      fs.writeFile('./public/assets/theme_templates/v3/posts_show.css', criticalCss); // Write the contents to a jekyll include
    });
  });
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The usual solution for Chef would be to turn the log level up to `DEBUG` to see the command output. No idea how you do that with current Opsworks. Most of the time these issues are either related to an environment variable like `$HOME` not being set or that `gulp` isn't being found correctly.

As a side note, I do not recommend using the `deploy` resource anymore. A normal `git` resource is probably better in general. See my `application_examples` cookbook for an example of a more modern Rails deployment with Chef.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. By default OpsWorks runs chef in debug mode. The output of the command is the first code block in my question, which doesn't really show anything useful. My guess is that if gulp weren't found, it would error out with a more useful message alluding to such. After all, I can ssh into the instance and run `gulp criticalCSS` with success as the deploy user. Can you expand on why you don't recommend using the deploy cookbook?

Comment: The `deploy` resource was built to match the structure of Capistrano. It has way more complexity and moving pieces than are required and in turn is very brittle.